# How to create new users for restored databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not too familiar with SQL Server and am facing the following problem: The server was freshly installed and the only existing login is `sa`.

Then a couple of databases were restored from earlier backups.

Now I'd like to run a few SQL scripts that create new users for these databases, running as `sa`, but am getting the message that I am not allowed to do this.

Comment: What's the error message that you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that database users have no matching server logins.

That is, each database [sys.database_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) has no match in [sys.server_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx)

For Windows logins this is easy. This generates your missing CREATE LOGINS

```
USE MyDB
SELECT
    'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(SUSER_SNAME(sid)) + ' FROM WINDOWS'
FROM
    sys.database_principals DP
WHERE
    DP.type IN ('G', 'U')
    AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals SP WHERE SP.sid = DP.sid);
```

For SQL Logins, you need to recreate it with the correct SID.

```
SELECT 
    'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(DP.name) + 
                ' WITH PASSWORD = ''ChangeMe'', SID = ' + 
                CONVERT(varchar(128), sid, 1)
FROM
    sys.database_principals DP
WHERE
    DP.type = 'S' AND DP.principal_id > 4 
    AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals SP WHERE SP.sid = DP.sid);
```

Note that [sp_change_users_login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) is deprecated.

Now, if your SQL Logins already exist, then the names match but the sid values are different. For this you use [ALTER USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx) use the LOGIN option.

Finally, the SQL Login passwords can be recreated if you have a backup of the "old" master database. If you restore this as, say, FixLogins then you can use this

```
SELECT 
    'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(DP.name) + 
                ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + CONVERT(varchar(256), SL.password_hash, 1) + ' HASHED, SID = ' + 
                CONVERT(varchar(128), DP.sid, 1)

FROM
    sys.database_principals DP
    JOIN
    FixLogins.sys.sql_logins SL ON DP.sid = SL.sid  
WHERE
    DP.type = 'S' AND DP.principal_id > 4 
    AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals SP WHERE SP.sid = DP.sid);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're trying to fix is what's known as "Orphaned Users" - I blogged about this a while ago, at http://thelonedba.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/restoring-into-a-different-environment-security-problem-orphaned-users/

However, without seeing your exact error message, it's hard to help you with specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree With Thomas Rushton.
If you have few users Use the Following Process.

1. Remove the users excepting the [dbo], guest, INFORMATION_SCHEMA, [sys]
2. and Then Add your users again by right clicking on Users-->New User option

This Processes is doing the same thing what Mr Thomas has suggested but it is manual process.